# ¿Como enviar alertas masivas en java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, spring-mvc

Uno de los requerimientos del cliente era enviar alertas masivas presionando un botón, siendo más específico enviar correos a todos los usuarios que pertenezcan a un área si es que sus contratos estaban por vencer. ¿Alguien sabe como hacer esto posible usando spring-boot framework? P.D: Ya tengo spring-email configurado.

Mi properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=XXXXXXXXXXXX
#Other properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Mi configuración:

```
@Service
public class Email {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendEmail(String subject, String content, String email) {

        MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);

            helper.setTo(email);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(content, true);
            
            

            javaMailSender.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de investigar finalmente pude encontrar una solución.Por ello les compartiré el siguiente código. Explicando un poco, lo que hago es
llamar a 2 listas, la primera es una lista de usuarios y la otra una lista de contratos. Luego recorro la lista de contratos y defino una condición. Si el plazo es menor a 6 meses recorro la lista de usuarios y si ambos comparten  la misma área envío un correo.

```
//Enviar alertas MASIVAS (Plazo)
        
        @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SADMIN"})
        @GetMapping("/alertas")
        public String alertas(Model model,
                 SessionStatus status,RedirectAttributes redirAttrs,BindingResult results) {    
            try {       
                    List<Users> listaUsers = uService.listar();                 
                    List<Contrato> listaContratos= cService.listar();
                    for (Contrato contrato:listaContratos) {

                        if(contrato.plazo() < 6) {
            
                        for (Users user :listaUsers) {
                            if (user.getArea().equals(contrato.getAg_area_usuario_con())) {
                                String mensajeCorreo = "<img src=\"https://unaimagen.svg\" alt=\"Consultora12345\"></br>";
                                mensajeCorreo += " <h2>Estimado(a) </h2>" + user.getName() +" <h2> Le queda menos de 6 meses al contrato: " + contrato.getAa_sie_con() +"</h2>"
                                + "</br>" + "Descripci&oacute;n: " + contrato.getAb_descripcion_servicio_con();                                     
                                try {
                                    emailService.sendEmail("Alerta de vencimiento de contrato", mensajeCorreo, user.getEmail());
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("errormessage", "No se pudo enviar el correo.");
                                    return "redirect:/contratos/listar";
                                } //catch 
                            }//if
                        }//for_user
                        }//if
                    }//Principal    
                    redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("successmessage", "Las alertas se enviaron correctamente.");
                    return "redirect:/contratos/listar";    
                
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("errormessage", "No se pudo enviar todas las alertas.");
                    return "redirect:/contratos/listar";
                }
        }
```

Este es el método plazo() el cual me ayuda a calcular los contratos que van a vender en menos de 6 meses.

```
            public int plazo() {
    Date today = new Date();
    
    int dias=(int) ((today.getTime()-am_fecha_inicio_con.getTime())/86400000);
    
    int dias2=(int) ((an_fecha_fin_con.getTime()-am_fecha_inicio_con.getTime())/86400000);
    
    int plazo =  (dias2-dias)/30;
    
    return plazo ;
}
```

Finalemnte escribí esto en la vista:

```
            <a th:href="@{/contratos/alertas}" class="btn btn-success"
            style='width: 210px; height: 37px;'
            onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro que deseas enviar alertas?(Recuerda que esta función puede demorar algunos minutos en ejecutarse)');">Enviar
            alertas(plazo)</a>
```

Cabe mencionar que debes de tener spring-email previamente configurado.